# Communicate with client side printer and print A4 sheet

Tags: javascript, java, printers, network-printers

Java web application installed in server. The client's can access the application using browser through URL. 
The application need to communicate with local printers or network printers which is directly connected to client and print pdf file in A4 sheet.

Here the print operation done by automatically without user interaction. User will just click print button, we need to find the default print setup in client machine and print pdf file in A4 sheet in that printer.

Multiple client machine and multiple default printer based on user setup.

How to do it using Java or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use method `print` on `window` object.

> The print() method prints the contents of the current window.
>
> The print() method opens the Print Dialog Box, which lets the user to select preferred printing options.

Example of usage:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to print the current page.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  window.print();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. We need to print pdf file. And also print automatically without user interaction when click 'Print' button. So probably find default printer which setup in client machine and print on that printer.

Comment: So you need to edit your question and give more details. You need to print pdf file from remote source or just from upload ?

Comment: This is the scenario, 1. User click print button from client machine. 2. Application take appropriate pdf file from remote server. 3. Need to find the network or default printer which setup in client machine and print that pdf file in that printer from client machine.